# this keyword is `undefined` in member function of a class

Tags: node.js, typescript

If I have an object of a class and I'm calling one of its public functions, the `this` keyword for some reason just shows up as `undefined`.

I tried some solutions from the internet, Stack Overflow and the TS docs. I read the docs for classes and how to access its member functions, but nothing helped me with this. I eventually found a workaround for this problem. But I am not satisfied with that. Because as per my understanding, I should be able to pass a function as an argument of another function. It may be that I am getting this whole thing wrong. Or JS's OOP just works differently. I would like an explanation as to why it is happening.

Following is the code I have written, including the problematic statement and the workaround I have implemented at the moment.

`router.ts`:

```js
import { Router } from "express";
import UserController from "./user.controller";

const userRouter = Router();
const userController = new UserController();

userRouter.post("/registerOrLogin", (req, res) => { //-> This works just fine.
    userController.registerOrLogin(req, res);
});

userRouter.post("/registerOrLogin", userController.registerOrLogin); //-> This gives me an error, where 'this' is undefined.

export default userRouter;
```

`UserController.ts`:

```js
//this is a function which I am trying to call from my router.ts file.
    public registerOrLogin(req: Request, res: Response): void {

        const reqAuthType = req.body.authType;
        const authType: AuthType = AuthType[reqAuthType as keyof typeof AuthType];

        if (!reqAuthType || !authType) {

            res.status(400).json({
                message: "AuthType is required.",
                node: "Extra Data is for dev information only. don't include this in for processing.",
                //authTypeDesc is an array defined in the constructor.
                extraData: this.authTypeDesc // -> This is a property where I was getting the error "can not read the property of undefined".
            });
            return;
        }
        res.status(200).json({ message: "hello...!" });
        this.authManager.registerLogin(req.body as IUser, authType);
    }
```